# Customize accessibility message - 3 fingers tap on UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, accessibility

I am working on an eBook reader book application where i am using UIPageViewController to provide the pageCurl effect. UIPageViewController is configured with 3 viewControllers to display the book content and it is configured to support the accessibility.

When the accessibility is enabled, Three fingers tap on the reader page plays the announcement as "Center of Screen". I would like customize the message like "Page x of y".

```
- (BOOL)isAccessibilityElement
{
    return YES;
}

- (UIAccessibilityTraits)accessibilityTraits
{
    return UIAccessibilityTraitCausesPageTurn;
}
```

The following properties/functions are also set

1. accessibilityPageContent
2. accessibilityLabel
3. accessibilityLineNumberForPoint
4. accessibilityContentForLineNumber
5. accessibilityFrameForLineNumber
6. accessibilityFrame

I don't see apple accessibility documentation to handle the 3 fingers tap.

How to customize the accessibility message on 3 fingers Tap?